# Sending Mails with Swiftmailer and Office 365 fails again

Tags: php, symfony, office365, swiftmailer

Trying to send Emails in **Swiftmailer 5.x** via **Office365**

This was working stable for a pretty while:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtp.office365.com
mailer_port: 587
mailer_user: me@mydomain.com
mailer_password: mypassword
mailer_encryption: tls
```

and still is the proposed solution in any recent answer/article I found but

this results now in:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Swift_TransportException: "**Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "me@mydomain.com" using 1 possible authenticators"** at .../vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php line 181

Of course I tripplechecked that username/password are correct and that I can use these credentials in other ways to send mails.

Comment: Have you read [this issue](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/497)? Someone had the same problem but didn't answer, maybe you can get help from them

Answer (score 0):

did you check the adress FROM  ?

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Subject')
                ->setFrom('me@mydomain.com')
```